# understanding pojo datasource in BIRT 4.3

Tags: birt

I have observed a strange behavior of BIRT 4.3 pojo data source. For my courseSubjects (It is a nested collection) even without creating a separate dataset the pojo data source that came with 4.3 worked well but when i am trying add another collection for another table in the same report but nothing is working out. My total report is being empty. If i create another dataset for that collection, everything is working fine. Why is this working for one collection and why not working for another collection? The behavior is too strange. It is not displaying any error and also not displaying any data. To view pdf report i am using the viewer provided by Eclipse Birt.

I am uploading the two rpt design files. "test.rpt" is the one which is working and before adding the "documentName" field to dataset, The "testNotWorking.rpt" is the one which is not working when i add "docName"  to the dataset. This is too strange. when it is working for courseSubjects why is it not working for "documents". How to understand this behaviour? As it is not allowing me to upload the documents taht are more than 111kb i am uploading to my google drive and providing the links to download. The following are the links

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B59LVhKQaKQYeFNDcnhxZ3pCWVE/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B59LVhKQaKQYcmoyZVVpZ1RCMlk/edit?usp=sharing

The following is the link for the jar file. I have hard coded the data for your convenience so that you will be able to see the report easily.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B59LVhKQaKQYa2RIUldGM0dfSm8/edit?usp=sharing